# NSFileManager - Check file size?

Tags: ios, nsfilemanager

I am recording sound file in one of my apps. I am trying to figure out how to get the file size of the recorded file?

I know how to get it and it's path, I just can not figure out how to get the file size.

Thanks
Shani

Answer (score 27, accepted):

you can use :

```
- (NSDictionary *)attributesOfItemAtPath:(NSString *)path error:(NSError **)error
```

to get the file property dictionary and can fetch `[dictObject valueForKey: @"NSFileSize"];`

Comment: There's also the method fileSize that is defined as a category in NSDictionary (NSFileAttributes), it's a lot cleaner than [dictObject valueForKey@"NSFileSize"].

Comment: Is there way to get directory size too ? just curious