# How to check empty Zip file in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, unzip, php-ziparchive

I have used **[ZipArchiver](https://code.google.com/archive/p/ziparchive/)** to unzip and it is working fine. But when it receives empty zip file, it goes error callback.

```
ZipArchive *za = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];

if ([za UnzipOpenFile: zipFilePath]) {

    //Valid zip file code goes here.

}else {

    //Unable to open zip file. May be empty or corrupted.
}
```

**Is there any method to check a zip is really empty or just unzip error. A `Boolean` value return will be most suitable solution.**

**Edit 1:** 
I need a method to check a zip has any files or its just empty files.

**Edit 2 :** 
As mentioned by @iphonic, we cannot relay on size of a empty zip file. It simply cannot be zero. In my case, I got 22Bytes for empty zip file size.

Comment: You are already checking it, whats the problem?

Comment: If in the path `zipFilePath` has valid empty zip file then it goes to error callback. Same error callback also called if the zip file is corrupter/invalid . So please tell me @iphonic how do i differentiate these 2  cases ? Thanks any way for your reply.

Comment: An Empty Zip file is considered as corrupt file, it can't be opened so the error, it is generalized error. Since you want to check file size try [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8844138/790842)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding file's size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5743856/finding-files-size)

Comment: No brother, it cannot be a zero file size. I got 22bytes. We cannot compare with file size and decide empty zip file.